# Save pdf without showing the user the print dialogue screen

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin.android and I followed [this](https://blog.xamarin.com/native-printing-with-android/)

I Want to save a print to a specific path without showing dialogue screen to user.

How can I say the path I want to save without asking user ?

I have that code:

```
myWebView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(this.Context);
var printManager = (Android.Print.PrintManager)Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.PrintService);
var text = new ContractHTML() { Model = new Model.Model() { img = null } };

myWebView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", text.GenerateString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

string fileName = "MyPrint_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pdf";
var printAdapter = myWebView.CreatePrintDocumentAdapter(fileName);
Android.Print.PrintJob printJob = printManager.Print("MyPrintJob", printAdapter, null);
```

This code is working and generate a pdf, but it's asking user where to save it, I want to save it in some path.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

> Save pdf without showing the user the print dialogue screen

**AFAIK you can not implement this feature in Android.**

The user needs to be able to choose some configuration, such as choosing what printer to print on. So when you use `printManager.Print()` method a print dialog will show up. You could find that In android [PrintManager Source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/print/PrintManager.java), `PrintManager` class is final(In C# it's sealed), we are not allowed to override this method to prevent the dialog.

When you  execute `printManager.Print("MyPrintJob", printAdapter, null)` method from an `Activity`, it starts `PrintJob` also it will bringing up the system print UI. This is did by  `Android` printing framework, we cannot silently print by using the  platform API.

There is an open issue on AOSP issue tracker : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160908.

Comment: Shen no, actually I was able to create a override of printAdapter and could create a pdf file without print dialogue, but that only saves a little part of view, to be more precise I show a WebView before and that only save the part I'm looking at, and the rest is just a blanc page.
So I think it's possible but can't get there yet

Comment: @micaelcunha, I think it's not a good idea to reinvent whole bicycle to avoid the dialog.

Comment: @YorkShen, it's nothing to do with good or bad, it's all about the clients' requests and you can do or just pass. BTW, there are real life application out there doing the job, we don't know how exactly they can approach it, or the solution is for industrial use (not for small business).

Answer (score 0):

After searching far and wide, I used this GitHub project to solve this problem. I was able to silently print the document without the user's knowledge.

It seems like the developer was able to add some classes to the `android.print` package to access private members, making this possible.

https://github.com/UttamPanchasara/PDF-Generator?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=7355